# How to serialize the FileUpload control? In SQL session handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, file-upload

I am using SQL Server session handling, as part of this I have to serialize all the data which is stored in session. On one page, I am storing the `FileUpload` control in session. How to serialize it?

My code is:

```
if (Session["FileUploadCer"] == null && fileUpload_Cer.HasFile)
{
    Session["FileUploadCer"] = fileUpload_Cer;
}
// Next time submit and Session has values but FileUpload is Blank 
// Return the values from session to FileUpload 
else if (Session["FileUploadCer"] != null && (!fileUpload_Cer.HasFile) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCertificateDetails.Text.ToString())))
{
    fileUpload_Cer = (FileUpload)Session["FileUploadCer"];

    if (!fileUpload_Cer.PostedFile.FileName.Equals(txtUploadCertificateFile.Text.ToString()))
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            CertificatePathIsInvalid = true;                              
            return;
        }
    }
}
// Now there could be another sictution when Session has File but user want to change the file 
// In this case we have to change the file in session object 
else if (fileUpload_Cer.HasFile)
{
    Session["FileUploadCer"] = fileUpload_Cer;
    //Label1.Text = fileUpload_Cer.FileName;
}
```